# SQL query doesn't return enough records

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a PHP application with a MySQL database back-end. I am trying to optimize a query. I have a table in my database that consists of 2780 records. I need to create a query that retrieves all of those records, and also shows human-readable information instead of ID numbers. I am trying to use JOIN statements to do that. Here is my query:

```
SELECT lde.gsfclde.id, lde.gsfclde.device_number,
lde.gsfcclassification.value as "classification",
lde.gsfccategory.value as "category", 
lde.gsfcldetypes.value as "type", lde.gsfclde.size,
lde.gsfclde.size_unit, lde.gsfcpower.value as "power",
lde.gsfcmanufacturer.value as "manufacturer", lde.gsfclde.capacity,
lde.gsfclde.serial_number, lde.gsfclde.model_number, lde.gsfclde.ecn,
lde.gsfclde.center, lde.gsfccode.value as "code",
lde.gsfcgprstatus.value as "gpr_status", 
lqms.labs_lab.lab_name as "lab", 
lqms.labs_lab.building as "building", 
lqms.labs_lab.room as "room", 
lqms.labs_person.first_name as "owner_first_name",
lqms.labs_person.last_name as "owner_last_name",
lde.gsfclde.criticality, lde.gsfclde.last_frequent,
lde.gsfclde.last_periodic, lde.gsfclde.last_load_test,
lde.gsfclde.next_frequent, lde.gsfclde.next_periodic,
lde.gsfclde.next_load_test from lde.gsfclde 
join lde.gsfcclassification on 
lde.gsfclde.classification_id = lde.gsfcclassification.id 
join lde.gsfccategory on 
lde.gsfclde.category_id = lde.gsfccategory.id 
join lde.gsfcldetypes on 
lde.gsfclde.type_id = lde.gsfcldetypes.id 
join lde.gsfcpower on 
lde.gsfclde.power_id = lde.gsfcpower.id 
join lde.gsfcmanufacturer on 
lde.gsfclde.manufacturer_id = lde.gsfcmanufacturer.id 
join lde.gsfccode on 
lde.gsfclde.code_id = lde.gsfccode.id 
join lde.gsfcgprstatus on 
lde.gsfclde.gpr_status_id = lde.gsfcgprstatus.id 
join lqms.labs_lab on lde.gsfclde.lab_id = lqms.labs_lab.id 
join lqms.labs_person on lde.gsfclde.owner = lqms.labs_person.id 
order by lde.gsfclde.device_number
```

The problem I have is that the query above only returns 2226 records. I assume that this is because some of the records in the LDE table have NULL values. I tried to add OR statements to each JOIN piece. For example:

```
join lde.gsfccode on (lde.gsfclde.code_id = lde.gsfccode.id or 
lde.gsfclde.code_id = NULL)
```

However, that query just spins and spins and never returns a result. So, how do I modify my query to also include records from the LDE table that may have NULL values?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Chris Martino

Comment: Hint: `LEFT JOIN`. :P

Comment: left join, outer join, or NVL wrappers are things to research

Comment: **Noting** equals to `NULL`, even another `NULL`. In general use `IS NULL` / `IS NOT NULL` instead. For your particular case, learn `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: You guys are awesome! I changed all my JOIN statements to LEFT JOIN and now I have all 2780 records! Thanks very much!

Comment: @cmarti10 You just completed stage 1! Try level 2 and understand what you just did.